# Correct proof or counterexample for the Homotopy Extension Lemma.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am fairly sure there is a mistake in the proof of the Homotopy Extension Lemma in Munkres (Lemma 62.1):

Let $X$ be a space such that $X \times I$ is normal. Let $A$ be a closed subspace of $X$, and let $f : A \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map, where $Y$ is an open subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $f$ is nulhomotopic, then $f$ may be extended to a continuous map $g : X \rightarrow Y$ that is also nulhomotopic.

In the proof, Munkres reasons:

Since $I$ is compact, the the tube lemma implies that there is an open set $W$ of $X$ containing $A$ such that $W \times I \subset U$. (lines 4-5, page 382)

But to apply the Tube Lemma, we need both $A$ and $I$ to be compact, not just $I$.

Am I correct that this is a mistake? If so, is the Homotopy Extension Lemma as stated true, and can you provide a correct proof? Or is there a counterexample where $A$ is closed but not compact?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps someone can correct me if I am wrong, but I believe Munkres is correct.

The tube lemma (Lemma 26.8) does not require compactness of both spaces. Rather, the tube lemma states that if $I$ is compact and $U$ is an open set of $X\times I$ containing $\{x\}\times I$, then there exists an open set $W_{x}$ of $X$ containing $x$ such that $W_{x}\times I \subseteq U$.

Because in the proof for the Homotopy Extension Lemma we have that $I$ is compact and there exists an open set $U$ of $X\times I$, containing $A\times I$, we can define $$\mathcal{W}:= \bigcup_{a\in A}W_{a}$$
where the $W_{a}$'s are the open sets obtained from the tube lemma. Then $\mathcal{W}$ is open in $X$ , contains $A$ and satisfies $\mathcal{W}\times I \subseteq U$.

Comment: You are not wrong!

Comment: There is an exercise in Munkres where he lets you prove this and calls that the tube lemma too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Is it exercise 9 you are referring too (The generalized tube lemma according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma))? I can not immediately see how this generalized version proves the above since we have not assumed $A$ to be bounded (i.e not compact). Do you have a hint on how to see the implication?

Comment: To be more precise, I do not see how the generalized version proves the above without  adding the extra argument with $\mathcal{W}$

Comment: I misremembered his version (the generalised version is called the Wallace theorem in most texts, for two compact sets). Here the union of the $W_a, a \in A$ easily suffices. And any unions of opens is open. The simple tube lemma suffices (plus AC)

Comment: Fun fact: there are normal spaces $X$ for which $X \times [0,1]$ is not normal (these are called Dowker spaces by definition). Research into their existence started because of this requirement in the homotopy extension theorem.